# Jhipster - Session Authentication Using Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, authentication, cors, jhipster

I have done the following things.

- Created Jhipster application with Http Session Authentication
- Enabled Cors.

I am trying to authenticate using the Jquery ajax. However I get the following error.

```
{
  "timestamp" : "2017-01-04T14:09:59.257+0000",
  "status" : 403,
  "error" : "Forbidden",
  "message" : "Invalid CSRF Token '16254aa2-e49d-41df-9602-ea32559617bd' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-XSRF-TOKEN'.",
  "path" : "/api/authentication"
}
```

I have spent more than two days trying to figure out, how to login using Jquery. Please help me if you can... :(

Below the Sample HTML I created to verify authentication.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-cookie.js"></script>
    <script lang="javascript">

    var domain = "127.0.0.1";


        // A $( document ).ready() block.
    $( document ).ready(function() {


        // This request will get the CSRF-TOKEN from the server and add it in the cookies

         $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url:"http://"+domain+":8080/",
            success: function(data, textStatus, request){
                    console.log("Get Request fired successfully.");
            },
            error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(request);
                    console.log(request.getResponseHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'));
            }
        });               

                           /**
                 * Function to get the cookie
                 */
                function getCookie(name) {
                    var cookieValue = null;
                    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
                        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    console.log("Cookie Value: " + cookieValue);
                    console.log("Document Cookie Value: " + document.cookie);
                    return cookieValue;
                }  


        // This ajax setup will add the XSRF-TOKEN saved in cookies to eery POST, PUT, DELETE request.
        // You dont need the tokens for GET request.
        $.ajaxSetup({
            beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                if (settings.type == 'POST' || settings.type == 'PUT' || settings.type == 'DELETE') {

                  //  if ((/^http:.*/   //.test(settings.url) || /^https:.*/.test(settings.url))) {
                        // Only send the token to relative URLs i.e. locally.
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-XSRF-TOKEN", getCookie('XSRF-TOKEN'));
                  //  }
                }
            }
        }); 

    });

    // Use this function for login
    function login(){
        var url = "http://"+domain+":8080/api/authentication";
        var username = $("#username").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();

        var data = 'j_username=' + encodeURIComponent(username) +
                '&j_password=' + encodeURIComponent(password) + '&remember-me=true'   + '&submit=Login';
        console.log("Calling Login");
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            success: function(){
                console.log("User logged in.");
            },
            error: function(response){
                console.log("Error in Login in.");
                console.log(response.responseText);
            }
        });       
    }





    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Login Example</h1>



    <div class="container">
      <label><b>Username</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" id="username" value="admin" required>

      <label><b>Password</b></label>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" id="password" value="admin" required>

      <button type="button" onclick="login();">Login</button>
    </div>


  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error tells you, that adding your XSRF token failed. This has nothing to do with CORS by the way.

As I see in the code, there already is a snippet to handle XSRF and it says the token is invalid. I guess your token is only fetched once per setup, rather then per each request, as it has to be.

Proof every single request is refreshing its token, so you dont place obsolete tokens to your headers